# Pdf Parsing, how to decompress text

Tags: ios, parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing

Hi am trying to parse a pdf file, am able to extract the Text from pdf, but if the pdf is compressed (using flatedecode), i get junk characters  so needed to know how to decompress the text, also how to know the filter used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use zlib library if working in c++ to do decompression of the bytes for the content stream of a page.